# Difference between pcase-let & cl-destructuring-bind?

Tags: elisp, let-binding, cl, elisp-conventions

I noticed both `pcase-let` and `cl-destructuring-bind` seem to perform the same operation.

Is there any difference or reason to use one instead of the other?

eg:

```lisp
(pcase-let ((`(,filename ,buf) (pop filename-and-buffer-list)))
  ;; do stuff.
  )
```

Seems to behave the same as:

```lisp
(cl-destructuring-bind (filename buf) (pop filename-and-buffer-list)
  ;; do stuff.
  )
```

Comment: Nothing more than personal preference, IMO.  `destructuring-bind` has been around much longer than `pcase`, and personally I find `pcase` forms harder to read; but YMMV.  I'd just say use whichever one you like best.

Comment: What @phils said. (And `cl-destructuring-bind` is a Common Lisp emulation, as you probably know.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cl-destructuring-bind` was designed more or less specifically to destructure data made of cons cells.  `pcase-let` on the other hand is just a special case of `pcase` which was designed to handle arbitrary data and be extensible (and be able to discriminate rather than only destructure).

So `cl-destructuring-bind` has a slightly more concise syntax for the simple cases like the one you show, whereas `pcase-let` imposes a more verbose syntax in exchange for the ability to destructure other data types such as structs, hash-tables, ...

Another difference is that `pcase-let` allows you to perform several such bindings, as in

```
(pcase-let ((PAT1 EXP1)
            (PAT2 EXP2)
            ...)
  ..)
```

whereas `cl-destructuring-bind` focuses on the single-pattern case, so you'd have to use

```
(cl-destructuring-bind PAT1 EXP1
  (cl-destructuring-bind PAT2 EXP2
    ...))
```

which again makes `cl-destructuring-bind` less verbose in the simple case.

As the designer&implementer of `pcase` I consider that the added verbosity cost of `pcase-let`s generality is minor (compared to the advantage of having a single syntax of patterns that works both for simple and complex cases).